# WPF -- Anyone know why I can't get this binding to reference?

Tags: wpf, binding

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stkWaitingPatients" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,-3"
   DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource local:oPatients}}">
```

I'm getting StaticResource reference 'local:oPatients' was not found.

Here is the codebehind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ListBox _activeListBox;
    clsPatients oPatients;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        oPatients = new clsPatients(true);

...
```

Comment: Your username shows as "unknown", you might want to edit your user profile.

Comment: When I started it asked for my google account or something and that's what happened...I'll work on it! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to address the object as a `StaticResource`, it needs to be in a resource dictionary. However, since you're creating the object in `MainWindow`'s constructor, you can set the `DataContext` in the code-behind like so.

```
oPatients = new clsPatients(true);
stkWaitingPatients.DataContext = oPatients;
```

And then change the `Binding` to this:

```
{Binding Mode=OneWay}
```

This is an ok practice if you're not going to be changing the `DataContext` again, otherwise you'd want a more flexible solution.

**Edit:** You mentioned `ObjectDataProvider` in your comment. Here's how you'd do that. First, add an `xmlns:sys` to the `Window` for the `System` namespace (I'm assuming you already have one for `xmlns:local`):

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then you can add an `ObjectDataProvider` to your resource dictionary like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider
        x:Key="bindingPatients"
        ObjectType="{x:Type local:clsPatients}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

And refer to it in a `Binding` with the `StaticResource` markup like this, using the same string we specified in the `x:Key` attached property we gave it in the dictionary:

```
{Binding Source={StaticResouce bindingPatients}, Mode=OneWay}
```

**Edit 2:** Ok, you posted more code in your answer, and now I know why it's throwing an exception during the constructor. You're attempting to do this...

```
lstWaitingPatients.DataContext = oPatients;
```

... but `lstWaitingPatients` doesn't actually exist until after `this.InitializeComponent()` finishes. `InitializeComponent()` loads the XAML and does a bunch of other things. Unless you really need to do something before all of that, put custom startup code **after** the call to `InitalizeComponent()` or in an event handler for `Window`'s `Loaded` event.

Comment: I'm simply trying to move the datacontext to the codebehind so that I can trap for errors (like a bad connection string) and then move to a user friendly error page...couldn't figure out how to do that using and ObjectDataSource in XAML...

Trying this now...

Comment: Nope, I'm getting a generic "Cannot create instance of Window"...can I send you more code?  This is driving me nuts!

Comment: That means you have an exception occuring during `Window`'s constructor, probably due to a bug in the XAML. Sending you more code won't help, seeing your code will. Did you put `xmlns:sys` inside the `Window` tag? Was there already a `<Window.Resources>` and now there are 2? There's a lot of things it could be.

Comment: And which one did you try? Assigning `DataContext` in code-behind?

Comment: Awww, I got it!  Duh, how about I put the DataContext assignment AFTER the InitializeComponent?!  

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following sets the ItemsSource in Code Behind and correctly handles the DataBinding:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        clsPatients oPatients = new clsPatients(true);

        //assuming oPatients implements IEnumerable
        this.lstWaitingPatients.ItemsSource = oPatients;
```

And the XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstWaitingPatients"       
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WaitingPatientsItemTemplate}"
         FontSize="21.333" Height="423.291"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         GotFocus="lstWaitingPatients_GotFocus"
         />
```

Comment: But, I'd go with the ObjectDataProvider from @Joel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I can't get this to work...I get a general Windows startup error.

Here is the codebehind with the Initializer and the class being instantiated:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ListBox _activeListBox;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        clsPatients oPatients = new clsPatients(true);
        lstWaitingPatients.DataContext = oPatients;

        this.InitializeComponent();
```

Here's the top of my XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Orista_Charting"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
x:Class="Orista_Charting.MainWindow"
x:Name="windowMain"
Title="Orista Chart"
Width="1024" Height="768" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Activated="MainWindow_Activated" >


<Window.Resources>        

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/OtherResources.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/TextBlockStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Converters.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Here's the pertinent XAML, as you see, I went ahead and moved the DataContext down to the ListBox from the StackPanel.  This doesn't run, but it does render in Design View (however, with no data present in the ListBox):

```
<!-- Waiting Patients List -->
    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF000000" Padding="10,10,10,10" 
            CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="15.245,187.043,0,41.957" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="stkWaitingPatients" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,-3"> 

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">    
                <TextBlock Text="Waiting Patients:" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="21.333" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,38.245,0" Width="139" Height="16" 
                Text="Minutes Waiting" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF9C2525" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                TextAlignment="Right"/> 
                <!-- Too be implemented, this is the wait animation -->
                <!--<Image x:Name="PollGif" Visibility="{Binding Loading}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="42.5" Height="42.5" 
                       Source="Images/loading-gif-animation.gif" Stretch="Fill"/>-->       
            </StackPanel>                  

            <ListBox x:Name="lstWaitingPatients"       
                     DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WaitingPatientsItemTemplate}"
                     FontSize="21.333" Height="423.291" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                     GotFocus="lstWaitingPatients_GotFocus"
                     />

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Ok, but if I just take comment out the assigment line in the codebehind, it does run (albeit with no data in the listbox):

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ListBox _activeListBox;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        clsPatients oPatients = new clsPatients(true);
        //lstWaitingPatients.DataContext = oPatients;
```

THANKS!

Comment: As sixlettervariables notes in his answer, you don't need some of the bindings you're doing on the `ListBox`.